# Rails 4 - Delete array element with remote: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have an array in the form and I made each array value render in a text field
with a delete button per field.
I understand how this is done if this was destroying an object but not sure where to look for if this was for array that needs to be destroyed with Ajax.

This is what I have at the moment but not sure what to do with the path and its parameters.

```
<% @recipe.steps.each_with_index do |arr, index| %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", some_path(?), method: :delete, remote: true %>
  <input type="text" value="<%= arr %>" name="recipe[steps][]">
<% end %>
```

And, in controller I'm not sure which action I should create because I have destroy action already in place for recipe object. I guess I should be passing in index value from the view and `pop` from the array using that index position. I'm just not sure where to compose this block.

I'd really appreciate some heads up.

Comment: Can you faux delete it using a checkbox and javascript, then actually delete it when `recipe` is submitted? This gives the user the time to undo the action.

Comment: That's certainly an option. I have some nested attributes in the same form that I've implemented Ajax destroy as simply removing it from dom and submit for update didn't work as expected with nested attributes. I guess I will just make all Ajax destroy to be consistent.

Comment: The drawback of doing it that way is that you will have to write some extra code to deal with the new action(assuming that you can create steps on the new action).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view :

```
<% @recipe.steps.each_with_index do |arr, index| %>
   <%= link_to "Delete", receipe_remove_path(arr), method: :delete, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

#receipes_controller.rb

```
def remove
   raise params.inspect 
   #inspect coming params and delete item as you need.
 end
```

#routes.rb

```
resources :receipes do 
  delete :remove #just added a custom action to perform your remove.
end
```

With raise params.inspect in your controllers action, when you hit this remove action, check your console.

1. This run time error lists the params coming to this particular
   action.
2. "Processing by SponsorsController#remove as JS" this remove as JS ensures you are hitting this action by ajax not a normal form submit.
3. Here in my case the parameters: {"sponsor_id" => 2} shows the record ID which I am intended to remove.

[image]

Comment: I've tried this but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Clicking on delete button doesn't do anything. This is the button in html `<a data-method="delete" data-remote="true" href="/recipes/01value/remove" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>`

Comment: as you have added remote: true option which will submit this link with ajax enabled. Please write raise params.inspect in your remove action. 
Then try to hit the link again & check in your console. The raise statement will list the params list to remove action.

Comment: Added a snap of expected params list in my answer. You will also hit something like this in your console. :)

Comment: Thanks. That explains it! Console prints `RuntimeError ({"action"=>"remove", "controller"=>"recipes", "recipe_id"=>"second"}):` and I guess I need to do some thing with recipe_id? Would you be able to show me how you could compose remove action based on this? I'm new to Rails. Thanks!

Comment: are you getting valid receipt_id => "second" ? This is what you were expecting ?

Comment: Yes. But I'm not sure why the key is called recipe_id as I'm trying to remove one of recipe attribute array element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68649/discussion-between-ajay-and-seong-lee).